# Is there any benefit to omitting the type="text/css" attribute on style tags used in HTML-Emails?

Tags: html, css, gmail, html-email

I'm wondering if anyone out there knows of any direct benefit to doing this in any email clients?

E.g.

```
<style>...</style>
```

vs

```
<style type="text/css">...</style>
```

Does Gmail still strip the style block regardless of whether we define the type?  How about other clients?

Comment: If any answer fits correct accept those for future references and to help future seekers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing in Litmus.  I can say it's safe to omit the type attribute from all Email Clients.  Any client that doesn't support embedded or external CSS will ignore them, and one's that do support embedded & external will recognize the file or style block as CSS.

Keeping the type attribute does not appear to be consequential either.  All clients showed no changes when swapping between omission and inclusion.

Answer (score 3):

The `type` attribute defines the media type of the `style` tag. It defines the browser that the content inside the `style` tag in CSS. Now HTML5 supports the omitted `type` in `style` tag also but some of the browsers need the `type` attribute to identify the CSS markups. **For example, chrome support without `type` attribute but old versions of Internet Explorer and Safari does not work.**

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.  It answers what the type attribute is, not whether it's going to cause any problems across e-mail clients.